# using mysql (too much data) to get statics about activity of different users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to make a query to get the data of top then users of some list ...later I will use php to statics and graphs but what I want is to get the sum of every single user but I find it difficult because in one month one single user can make many registers on database and I want to manage it and then get the top ten of users who have more activities (on this case with more quantity per month).

Example

```
user_id     quantity      date      kind
user1     23          17/03/18   free
user1      3           17/03/18  charge
user2      5          17/03/18   free
user2      5          17/03/18    free
user2      8           18/03/18   free
user3      9           19/03/18   free
user3      1           20/03/18   free
user3      1          20/03/18    charge
user3     3           20/03/18    charge
user3     5           20/03/18    charge
```

Comment: What is this example?  Input data?  Output data?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a simple count query will do the job that you want. Something like this:

```
Select user_id, sum(quantity) as activity-count
From ActivityTable
Group By user_id
Where kind = something; # (Optional)
```

I don't have so much information here about your database, so all I got is a direction for your target task.

A little test that I have run:

**Table:**

```
userid, quantity, date, kind
'0', '3', '2017-03-18', 'charge'
'0', '23', '2017-03-18', 'free'
'0', '3', '2018-03-18', 'charge'
'2', '5', '2017-03-18', 'charge'
'2', '5', '2017-03-18', 'free'
'2', '8', '2018-03-18', 'free'
'3', '9', '2019-03-18', 'free'
'3', '1', '2020-03-18', 'charge'
'3', '1', '2020-03-18', 'free'
'3', '3', '2021-03-18', 'charge'
'3', '3', '2022-03-18', 'charge'
```

**Query:**

```
Select userid, month(date) as 'month', sum(quantity) as activity_count
From table1
Group By userid, month(date)
```

**Result:**

```
userid, month, activity_count
'0', '3', '29'
'2', '3', '18'
'3', '3', '17'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store arrays in a database by serializing them, inserting them into the database, and then unserializing them when you retrieve from the database.

Arrays can be multidimensional in PHP, that means that arrays can store arrays and so on. Also arrays can be relational, meaning that you can store values and give an identifier ('key') to each value.

Knowing that, you can do stuff like:

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?;');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array();

if ($array_data = unserialize($result['data'])) {

    echo 'The quantity related to ', $result['name'], ' is ', $array_data['quantity'];

} else {

    echo 'It seems that there\'s nothing related to ', $result['name'], ' yet. Adding a field now.';

    $array_data = array(

        'quantity' => 23,
        'date' => date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'),
        'kind' => 'free'

    );

}

$array_data = serialize($array_data);

$stmt2 = $con->prepare('UPDATE users SET data=? WHERE user_id=?;');
$stmt2->bind_param('ss', $array_data, $id);
$stmt2->execute();
```

The example above is pretty abstract, but you can get a grasp of what you can do with serialization and arrays. MySQL does not have an "array" type, but you can use serialize and unserialize with almost all objects in PHP to store them in databases.

Note that the serialized fields' type in MySQL should be "BLOB".

Answer (score 0):

This query should return you the list of top 10 users for the month:

```
select user_id, SUM(quantity) as qty
from table_name
group by user_id
where  MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(date) AND
YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) = YEAR(date)
Order by qty DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```